# compiling HTML5 to .exe/.dmg

Tags: html, compiler-construction, exe, dmg

I am currently beginning a project where we want to build an Interactive Whiteboard (educational activities) and deploy via CD-ROM. I want to build the project in HTML5 for it's interactivity and then somehow compile it to both .exe. and .dmg so when the CD-ROM is inserted it autoplays the 'Game'.

How is this possible? Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I already made a project using pure C (**WinAPI**) on github that can pack **HTML** files into **single EXE** using resources.

http://github.com/dns/WinAPI-Embed-Browser/releases

Use: `res://programname.exe/test.html` as path to access html files from your EXE file.

From here you also can hide the window border & just showing the content of your HTML app, or even running on fullscreen. This is very useful if you want to make **interactive CD-ROM**.

On Mac, you can use Delphi/Lazarus TWebBrowser control to load html files. However I don't know if mac program can access files from resource or not.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 is a browser technology, so I think as long as the pc you are installing on has the latest browsers, installing your app should work fine.
Can you tell us why you want it as a CD-ROM based installation, where as you can easily host it online?

Comment: I'm worried about hosting online due to people not having the latest browser, especially seeing as it will be going to a lot of different schools. Basically I'm working for a publishing company, and the book will include the CD-ROM with it attached to the back cover, it doesn;t need to be installed, just run straight from the disc like an autoplay app.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need any .exe wrapping. Here is an approach.

> Important: your autorun will be often disabled, [not so] quietly. Provide some instructions for running your application  manually.

So:

- Google for running a portable version of Firefox or Chrome from a CD. Have the browser prepared. Put it in a [sub]directory representing your CD.
- Put your content there.
- Create a .cmd file to invoke the browser with a command like,

  FirefoxPortable.exe index.html
- Create autorun.inf (details googlable) to call the above batch file.
- Make a CD image from that directory. There are lots of CD burning applications that can do that.
- Test.

Comment: for Windows users, you can see my answer.